# Why doesn't my program properly read from my text file?

Tags: python, database, tkinter, text-files, txt

I made a text file with a list of usernames and passwords. My program (in a tkinter page) is supposed to check whether the username and password exists in the file, and then if it doesn't it makes a label that says 'username or password incorrect[image]'. However, even when the username and password clealy exists in the text file, it will still print the 'incorrect' message. Here's an example of something in my text file:

```
testusername.testpassword
```

And here is the code that's supposed to detect it:

```
def login_incorrect():
    Label(loginPage, text="Username or password incorrect.").place(x=120, y=120)
    # print("def login incorrect")
def LoginToAccount():
    print("def login to account")
    # while True:  # This loop will run as long as the user is not logged in.
    with open('AccountDatabase.txt'):
        if loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get() not in open('AccountDatabase.txt').read():
            login_incorrect()
            print('incorrect')
            print(loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get())
```

But when I write `testusername` in the username field and `testpassword` in the password field, it still shows the error. Here's a screenshot:

Why can't I detect if text is in a text file?

Comment: Please show the error as text.

Comment: There is no error, nothing is written on the console

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `open('AccountDatabase.txt').read()` is returning what you expect? Have you verified that `loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get()` is returning what you expect? Most likely you are making a false assumption about one or the other. Also, are you aware that you're opening the file twice?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  Is the text file in different encoding, for example "utf-16"?

Comment: @BryanOakley I checked `loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get()` and it works fine. How do I verify `open('AccountDatabase.txt').read()`?

Comment: `data=open('AccountDatabase.txt').read(); print(data)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley It returns nothing. Is that normal? If not how do I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: If it returns nothing, then that's your problem since your username/password isn't in that "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you first need to read the file, and only then check for the occurrence of the desired one.

```
with open('AccountDatabase.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_logins = f.read()
    if loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get() not in file_logins:
        login_incorrect()
        print('incorrect')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I fixed opening the file for read and the condition.

```
def login_incorrect():
    Label(loginPage, text="Username or password incorrect.").place(x=120, y=120)
    # print("def login incorrect")
def LoginToAccount():
    print("def login to account")
    # while True:  # This loop will run as long as the user is not logged in.
    with open('AccountDatabase.txt', 'r') as f:

        if loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get() not in f.read():
            login_incorrect()
            print('incorrect')
            print(loginUsernameE.get() + '.' + loginPasswordE.get())
```

Comment: There is still the same error unfortunately